# How do you make a confirmation message stay put after submitting a form?

Tags: jquery, forms, confirmation

I'm trying to make a simple newsletter signup form that consists of an email address field and submit button. When the user enters their address and hits submit, I want a confirmation message to appear below the form. What actually happens is the message appears and immediately disappears. How do I make it stay put? Here is my code:

```
<body>
    <form id="newsletter_signup"> <!-- form action to be added later -->
        <p><input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="your@email.com" />
        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe"></p>
        <div id="feedback"></div>
    </form>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $('#newsletter_signup').submit(function() {
        var email_address = $('#email').val();
        $('#feedback').html('Thanks! ' + email_address + ' has been signed up.');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You need to send your data using ajax. Your current implementation sends the data to the page defined in the `form` tag (which is undefined, and therefore the page itself) and reloads the page with the data it gets back from the server. You can also choose to alter the page based on the data the server receives.

Answer (score 3):

Change your code to this, submitting the form via Ajax request instead:

```
$('#newsletter_signup').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('newsletter_signup', function (data){
       var email_address = $('#email').val();
       $('#feedback').html('Thanks! ' + email_address + ' has been signed up.');
    });   
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The form is being submitted, which refreshes the page. So your message is displaying for an instant before the page is reloaded. You could either use ajax to submit the form so the page doesn't reload, or you could use server-side code to display your thank you message.

As a side note, your code is vulnerable to XSS where you display the user's email address on the page.

Answer (score 2):

It's disappearing because, by submitting the form, you are basically refreshing the entire page.

To work around this, you would need to do one of three things (there may be other ways too):

- Use an AJAX call to submit your form;
- Alter the code behind it to trigger the message's appearance when the page is returned to the browser after the round-trip to the server; or,
- Set a cookie prior to the round-trip that is picked up when control returns, that triggers the message to appear.

The implementation of much of this functionality would be specific to the language you're using on the server-side.